# Spring Roo - update a deployed entity

Tags: jpa, spring-roo, alter-table

Suppose that using Spring Roo, I have created a web-app with a "User" entity storing user data. It has two string fields firstname and lastname.

I deploy this to production and Users get created and saved in DB.

I now would like to add a field, say dateOfBirth to the entity. This is easily done using Roo.

How is updating of the DB table in the background done? Can I just redeploy over the previous war and the DB gets automagically updated?

How / where can I define how the existing DB entries which lack the DOB are handled (eg. put in an "n/a" value).

Links to relevant docs are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DDL generation strategy is configured in `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

For hibernate, use the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-question-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do) describes the meaning of this property.

For eclipselink, use the property `eclipselink.ddl-generation`.  This [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL) gives more information on configuring DDL generation in eclipselink.

I think things are a bit more involved if you are using datanucleus or openjpa as your persistence provider.